# Video Mining - Character Identification and Naming

Tags: java, video-processing, jmf

Is there any class to add subtitles in video using JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Jubler](http://www.jubler.org/) to add,edit subtitles in video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [Jubler](http://www.jubler.org/) as suggested by `u3050`.

But the following link explains `step-by-step` the things need to be done to add,edit subtitles in video. Go through it.

- [Create,edit,embed subtitles through Jubler in video files](http://www.my-guides.net/en/content/view/105/26/)

Answer (score 0):

Jubler will not hard-burn subtitles on a video file.
There is an experimental approach in the development tree of Jubler which can produce images of subtitles (PNG files) but it won't be able to hard burn it.
You'll need another application for that unfortunately.